# Rotate QGraphicsItem with ItemIsMovable attribute after move

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, qgraphicsitem

I am having problems with object rotation about the object center after using the predefined move option in Qt.  I create an QGraphicsRectItem and set the ItemIsMovable attribute.  The rotations work just fine (Shift left mouse click and drag on the item).

Now move the rectangle, (Shift left mouse drag) and try rotating again.  The rotation is incorrect.   I calculate the center of the rectangle using the sceneBoundingBox().normalize.center().  If I draw that point after the move, it is in the correct location.

I have tried both setOriginTransform and using the QTransform method.  They both give me the same results.

Am I confused about the coordinate systems of the scene vs. the rotation coordinate system?  How does that change after the move?

Here is a stripped down compilable header file and source code that demonstrates the problem.  I am using Qt 5.7 on a Mac.  The rotations are calculated in the function rotateItem(...) all coordinates should be in the scene coordinate system.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QPen>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include "myrect.h"


// THIS IS THE PROBLEM FUNCTION
// calculate rotations about the center of a given shape item.
void rotateItem(QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem* shape, QPointF center,
                QPointF moved, QPointF initial_pos)
{
  // get the angle from the center to the initial click point
  qreal init_x = initial_pos.x() - center.x();
  qreal init_y = initial_pos.y() - center.y();
  qreal initial_angle = std::atan2(init_y, init_x);
  qreal x = moved.x() - center.x();
  qreal y = moved.y() - center.y();

  qreal mv_angle = std::atan2(y,x);

  // get the changed angle
  qreal angle = (mv_angle - initial_angle)*180/M_PI;

  if (std::fabs(angle) > 360.0)
    angle = 0.0;

  // both transforms give the same result
  QTransform xform;
  xform.translate(center.x(), center.y());
  xform.rotate(angle);
  xform.translate(-center.x(), -center.y());

  shape->setTransform(xform, false);
  //shape->setTransformOriginPoint(center);
  //shape->setRotation(angle);
}



MyRect::MyRect(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height) :
      QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height)
{
  mInitialPos.setX(0.0);
  mInitialPos.setY(0.0);

  mInitialCenter.setX(0.0);
  mInitialCenter.setY(0.0);
}

void MyRect::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
  {
    //if (event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)
    if (event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier)
    {
      // ALL COORDINATES ARE IN THE SCENE COORDINATE FRAME (is that a problem?)
      mInitialPos = event->scenePos();
      mInitialCenter = this->sceneBoundingRect().normalized().center();
    }
    else
      QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem::mousePressEvent(event);
  }
}

void MyRect::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  if (event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
  {
    if (event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier)
    {
      // Call the rotation function
      rotateItem(this, mInitialCenter, event->scenePos(), mInitialPos);
      event->accept();
    }
    else
    {
      QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }
  }
}

void MyRect::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)
{
  QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}



QGraphicsItem* add_rectangle(QGraphicsScene* scene)
{
  MyRect* rectangle = new MyRect(-50, 10, 80, 80);

  QBrush red_brush(Qt::red);
  QPen pen(Qt::black);
  pen.setWidth(4);

  rectangle->setBrush(red_brush);
  rectangle->setPen(pen);
  rectangle->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

  scene->addItem(rectangle);

  return rectangle;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QWidget w;

  QGraphicsView* graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(&w);
  graphicsView->setGeometry(0,0,500,500);
  QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(&w);
  graphicsView->setScene(scene);

  add_rectangle(scene);

  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Here is the stripped down object header file
    #ifndef MYRECT_H
    #define MYRECT_H
    #include 
    #include

```
class MyRect : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    MyRect(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height);

    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event);

  private:
    QPointF mInitialPos;
    QPointF mInitialCenter;
};

#endif // MYRECT_H
```

Answer (score 0):

The item coordinate system is local to the item. The Qt documentation states this but maybe not clearly enough to get it through my brain.

The angular rotation coordinate system is in the scene coordinate system.  I had to separate the item translate coordinates from the angular rotation coordinates.  The angle is calculated about center1 and item is rotated about center.

Thus the rotateItem method becomes:

```
void rotateItem(QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem* shape, QPointF center1,
                QPointF moved, QPointF initial_pos)
{
  QRectF bbox = shape->boundingRect().normalized();
  QPointF center = bbox.center();  // item translate

  // get the angle from the center to the initial click point
  qreal init_x = initial_pos.x() - center1.x();
  qreal init_y = initial_pos.y() - center1.y();
  qreal initial_angle = std::atan2(init_y, init_x);
  qreal x = moved.x() - center1.x();
  qreal y = moved.y() - center1.y();

  qreal mv_angle = std::atan2(y,x);

  // get the changed angle
  qreal angle = (mv_angle - initial_angle)*180/M_PI;

  if (std::fabs(angle) > 360.0)
    angle = 0.0;

  // both transforms give the same result
  QTransform xform;
  xform.translate(center.x(), center.y());
  xform.rotate(angle);
  xform.translate(-center.x(), -center.y());

  shape->setTransform(xform, false);
}
```